# Whats the right way to use Jersey with hibernate DAOs?

Tags: java, hibernate, jersey

I´m developing a Jersey application with hibernate, but i don't know the right way to use these tecnologies without getting a messy code.

I have just created a class that I call `DataProvider`. It is an abstract class that gets a generic `POJO` and performs actions on like `save`, `list`, `update`, `delete` and `listAll`. Then I created DAO classes for every table that extends `DataProvider`. These DAO´s are called in a JSONService class that serves JSON with the Jersey API.

Anyone have some idea about whats the right way?

Comment: This is a mostly used design approach. I want to know what issue you've encountered with this pattern.

Comment: Ok, i just want to be sure that is a commom approach, because i´m getting some messy methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shortly, do the following:

1. Create and implement basic DB object wich contains the id. All other db entities must extend BaseDbObject (JPA Ineritance). This solution will let you use the Generics in all their beauty and simplicity.
2. Create a data access object (DAO) to CRUD operations with basic object and its hierarchy (JPA and all the stuff implemented with Hibernate).
3. Create a service to manipulate with basic object in terms of business process. It must use DAO to persist object's state (EJB, Spring).
4. Create the endpoint for REST API (JAX-RS, Jersey) and connect it with the service via DI. Also support XML or JSON serialization of your entities. For example with Jackson.

Good example of doing this you can find [here](https://github.com/philipsorst/angular-rest-springsecurity). If you want to improve the data-access-layer use [AppFuse](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/AppFuse+QuickStart) implementation.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: @Maksim regarding your first bullet, how can you make that class if every table object needs to annotate its key with a different column name?

Comment: @YonatanNir where did you found this restriction?